# PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod alternative in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have this lines in my previous code

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize'  => '32MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
```

Now I am trying to migrate to PhpSpreadsheet.

I am able to find class \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings and methods setCache() and getCache(). But still not able find this options what i have.

Can anyone provide a way or an example to do what i am doing in PHPExcel into PhpSpreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Caching was rewritten in PhpSpreadsheet (see [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/#cell-caching)). If you need other caching options, you have to write your own PSR-16 cache or use one of the libraries mentioned in the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/memory_saving/).